# MySQL stored procedure cases for IN function

Tags: mysql

I'm facing a dilemma where I have to build a string based on the parameter.

```
CASE gender_Case
WHEN CONCAT("1") THEN
SET @tempString = CONCAT('M');
WHEN CONCAT("2") THEN
SET @tempString = CONCAT('F');
ELSE
SET @tempString = CONCAT('M','F');
END CASE;
```

The Query I'm going to build is :

```
SELECT @uid:=uid FROM search_optimized_table where country = country 
and uid !=userId and TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,DOB,CURDATE()) 
BETWEEN minAge and maxAge and gender IN (@tempString)
```

For case 1 and 2 is working fine.
But other than case 1 and case 2. It just fails.

Any idea how to fix it?

Scenario:

> When caller receives case 1 , it will create the query for gender IN
>   (M). But in my issue, case 3 always fails.

EDIT:

```
CASE gender_Case
     WHEN CONCAT("1") THEN
     SET @tempString = "M";
     WHEN CONCAT("2") THEN
     SET @tempString = "F";
     ELSE
     SET @tempString = "M,F";
     END CASE;
```

The First and Second above works but not the third.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the whole query to a different version using concat in my Query itself.
For the case:

```
CASE gender_Case
    WHEN CONCAT("1") THEN
    SET @tempString = "gender IN ('M')";
    WHEN CONCAT("2") THEN
    SET @tempString = "gender = ('F')";
    ELSE
    SET @tempString = "gender IN ('M','F')";
    END CASE;
```

For query building:

```
SET @query = CONCAT('INSERT INTO temp_local_search(
             SELECT @uid:=uid FROM search_optimized_table 
             where country = ',country,' and uid !=',userId,' and 
             TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,DOB,CURDATE()) BETWEEN ',minAge,' and ',maxAge,' and ',@tempString,';');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the part of query as follows, and let me work if it worked or not:

```
CASE WHEN gender_Case="1" THEN SET @tempString = "'M'";
     WHEN gender_Case="2" THEN SET @tempString = "'F'";
     ELSE SET @tempString = "'M','F'";
END; 

SET @Query = CONCAT("SELECT @uid:=uid FROM search_optimized_table where country = country 
and uid !=userId and TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,DOB,CURDATE()) 
BETWEEN minAge and maxAge and gender IN (",@tempString,") ");

PREPARE stmtForQuery FROM @Query;
EXECUTE stmtForQuery;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmtForQuery;
```

(Note: we do have two syntax for CASE in MySql. One is the way you have implemented, and the other is this one. That wont make any difference. What I have changed is the string that you will use for parameters of IN.)

Comment: try this now, i mistakenly added case after end;

Comment: no luck too. but the first and second work for me for this :
``` CASE WHEN gender_Case="1" THEN SET @tempString = "M";
        WHEN gender_Case="2" THEN SET @tempString = "F";
       ELSE SET @tempString = "M,F";
      END CASE;  ```

Comment: is there any issue in the query that you have added in the comment?

Answer (score 0):

Why not have 2 tempstrings

```
 IF GENDER_CASE = 1 THEN
     SET @ASTRING = 'M';
     SET @BSTRING = 'M';
    ELSEIF GENDER_CASE = 2 THEN
     SET @ASTRING = 'F';
     SET @BSTRING = 'F';
    ELSE 
     SET @ASTRING = 'M';
     SET @BSTRING = 'F';
    END IF;
```